# Localized speech recognition throwing ArgumentException

Tags: c#, localization, speech-recognition, system.speech.recognition

I have the following problem:

I am using a German Windows7-machine (Culture: "de-DE"), but I want to use the `SpeechRecognitionEngine`-class with an other culture.

However, the following code throws an `ArgumentException`:

```
using (SpeechRecognitionEngine rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-GB"))) //ArgumentException
{
    rec.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar("grammar:dictation#spelling"));
    rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;
    rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    ...
}
```

The Exception message is the following:

> *Es wurde kein Erkennungsmodul mit der erforderlichen ID gefunden.*

Translation:

> *No recognition module with the required ID could be found.*

Does this mean, that some sort of language package is missing on my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the `en-GB`-packet has to be installed on the machine.

EDIT:
It would be also reasonable to use a try catch block to prevent the app from crashing if the packet is not available.